# Question with too much proven working code, what to do?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426927/how-to-join-lists-created-with-for-loop) runs through the OP's entire script, explaining the process of how all the results gathered right up to the last step where they want to know how to collapse results, which is a much more simple problem (likely even a dupe), but how should it handled given that it's not wrong so much as unnecessary?

Comment: @Tanner What I felt was a problem is that it's so long that it makes it harder to parse and understand, even though the actual issue is small and relatively easily answered. This both makes it harder to answer, since you wade through unnecessary info, and then if other users come across is later, they might get confused trying to understand the question.

Comment: @Tanner disregard the +4, it's a crappy question. OP says "Now I try to explain every line of code, so you can see if there's some mistake" - that's so far removed from useful that I downvoted the question because of it. OP writes a ton of useless code and their general approach to solving the problem is rather bad or at least totally unpythonic (which is somewhat expected of someone new to programming) - explaining all the tiny "mistakes" would be far too broad. The best approach to solve this would be to just rewrite the code, so explaining the bad code doesn't help anybody.

Comment: Not to mention the question morphs into a new and different one at the end.

Comment: If the user really does want someone to comb through his or her script for additional feedback, it would be helpful to point him or her to CodeReview.SE.

Comment: I am surprised there aren't more close votes on that question.  There's nothing minimal about it.

Comment: He's a new user to the site, English is not his native language and he made a great effort to express himself for his question, and people bombarded him with downvotes? Times like this make me hate SO.

Comment: This is always a hard problem, as it's hard to know exactly the right balance between too little code to demonstrate the problem and too much code that isn't relevant. It gets easier with experience, and I agree the questioner put *way* too much code even for someone who is new to the site, but it is still a hard problem in general.

Comment: Engineering principle :- implement the necessary and sufficient, then stop The second is KISS:- keep it simple and stupid

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'd leave a comment for the OP explaining that they've put too much code into their post, if it looks like they're still responding to comments. You can close it as a duplicate if you find one, otherwise you can use this close reason:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
>   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and *the
>   **shortest** code necessary to reproduce it* in the question itself.

I don't think editing a question to remove a huge chunk of content, even if it really isn't needed, is going to go over well with reviewers. The OP is likely to roll something like that back and complain as well.

Comment: If there really is a good core question being obscured by miles of needless code, by all means edit it. Sadly you're probably right that you're at high risk of rejection from many reviewers, who will just innappropriately slap the 'radical change' rejection reason, but many will recognise that you're removing noise and approve the edit, especially if you use the edit summary to explain your actions. Whether such an edit is worthwhile in *this* case, I dunno; I didn't care enough to read the huge question.